# Can't uninstall Xcode 13 Beta

Tags: ios, xcode

I am fairly new to all of this, sorry if my description lacks information.

I accidentally downloaded the Xcode 13 beta (Version 13.0 beta (13A5154h)) and installed it on my MacBook Pro 13 inch, 2020. For various reasons, I can't use the beta build and I need to uninstall it and remove all its components so I can then install the current version from the App store.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to uninstall the application?! I can't even find the application icon. Par example, there is nothing under /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/ or /Developer/Applications. The regular /Applications also shows nothing.

Does anyone know what I could do to get rid of it?

Thanks for helping me out!

Best
Jerome

Comment: That's not the regular applications path. That's for the user. Root applications directory is `/Applications`

Comment: Thanks! You are right of course, I edited the post to reflect that. /Applications contains no Xcode icon/file.

Comment: If you can't find it how do you know you have it?

Comment: Also: "so I can then install the current version from the App store." So just install it. What's stopping you? They can coexist.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure they can coexist, it just takes up quite a bit of space and sounds like a problem waiting to happen.

I figured it out btw: Xcode somehow ended up in a weird directory. After finding and deleting it, I followed these instructions developer.apple.com/forums/thread/110227 (they are for Xcode 10 but work just as well her